# Is Kiroumaru really a bakenezumi?

Tags: from-the-new-world

**Warning: Answers may contain (hopefully hidden) spoilers from the end of the series.**

Kiroumaru is a leader of the bakenezumi (monster rats or queerats) but he looks a lot different from all the other ones in the show.

[image: Picture of Yakomaru and Kiroumaru next to each other]

On the left is Yakomaru, who looks like pretty much every other bakenezumi in the show. On the right is Kiroumaru who is quite different from Yakomaru. In a few of the episodes, I think I heard characters refer to Kiroumaru as a bakenezumi, and nobody questioned why he looks so different. Is he really a bakenezumi, or is he some other species that joined a bakenezumi tribe?

Answer (score 5):

Think of Queerats as humans (WINK WINK). A person can be Asian, Caucasian, etc. So, there are many different types of Queerats too; some of them have horns, some have smaller teeth and (in this case) some of them are tall.

HOWEVER. There IS a speculation regarding Kiroumaru's height that involves the origin of the Queerats. It's a last ep spoiler:

> Since Queerats are from non-PK humans, Kiroumaru's height might come from this. It might mean that he or his race didn't "evolve" properly into Queerats. Or, Kiroumaru's race might be tall in the first place. That is, when they were still humans, they were tall. So, when they turned into Queerats, they're tall too.

Hope that helps you :D

Comment: Wasn't it revealed at the end that queerats were mole rat + (you know what) DNA? I can see the you know what, but I'm at a loss for the mole rat part...